# How to diagnose multicollinearity using the output of vif function in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multicollinearity

I am running a logistic regression in R and am attempting to determine if multicollinearity is a problem with my model.
 When I run `vif()` on my final model, I get `GVIF` and `GVIF^1/(2*Df)` columns. From what I have read `GVIF^1/(2*Df)` is what I should use to assess muticollinearity, but I have been unable to determine what values I should use as a cut-off point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before modelling, you should look at correlations between your (assumed) independent variables. I think you should rephrase your question to "how to identify multicolinearity" and ask on crossvalidated.com, instead.

Comment: The same issue is discussed here with some more conclusions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70679/which-variance-inflation-factor-should-i-be-using-textgvif-or-textgvif/96584#96584