# How to verify multicollinearity for categorial variables?

Tags: categorical-data, multicollinearity

I want to verify for multicollinearity between independent categorial variables. Which test I should use? First, I want to examine the relationship between the willingness to participate in medical decision making (dependent variabele - 2 categories) and education (independent variable).

Later, I would do a multiple binary logistic regression (adjusted). I have education (5 categories), paid work (2 or 3 categories) and household income (2 categories). Income was questioned using a 5-point likert scale.

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about why you think you need to test multicollinearity among these variables. It's not usually a problem in this type of study, and once you fit the model you can [evaluate it directly from the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/457970/28500). Also, please explain why you are treating income as categorical, as it's usually a [bad idea to bin a continuous variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/230750/28500). Please provide extra information by editing the question; comments are easy to overlook.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to pre-test for multicollinearity in a study like this. That can be an issue in large-scale studies with many potential predictor variables, so it gets a lot of attention in machine learning courses. Even if you found multicollinearity, how would you change the modeling strategy for your studies?

All that multicollinearity will do here is inflate the variance estimates for individual coefficients.* It probably won't hurt predictions from the models at all, as the high individual variance of one coefficient will typically be offset by corresponding covariances with other coefficients.

If you are worried about multicollinearity, fit a model and then use the `vif()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) to calculate the variance inflation factors (VIF) directly from the model. As [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/457970/28500) explains, the VIF produced by that function are appropriate both for categorical predictors and for models other than ordinary least squares, situations where the [usual VIF calculations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) are inappropriate.

---

*If the collinearity is perfect then there might be a problem, but that just means that some of your predictors are exact linear combinations of others. Software will often just remove such a predictor from the model before it does the fitting.